# File permission mask/mode settings for Samba on FreeNAS?

Tags: permissions, samba, chmod, truenas, setgid

I'm currently working on the Samba settings on a FreeNAS server. When any user creates a file or a folder on the server I want the file or folder to get the following RWX permissions:

```
Folders: drwxrws---
Files: -rwxrws---
```

To set the permissions like this manually I use chmod 2770 which works great. But I want this to happen automatically and therefore I've added the following lines to smb.conf:

```
create mask = 2770
directory mask = 2770
force create mode = 2770
force directory mode = 2770
```

But when I test by creating a file in one of the folders it get's these permissions:

```
Folder: drwxrwx
File: -rwxrw----
```

What am I overlooking or doing wrong? Is the order of the lines relevant? Does the setgid digit (the 2 in 2770) mess things up?

Comment: Which Samba version are you using?

Comment: Just a note: Unless you have a very special situation you probably do not want your files to have the set-gid bit set. For the directories it makes sense but not for the normal files.

Comment: quanta: I'm using FreeNAS version 0.7.2. In this I think version 3.5.5 of Samba is included.

Comment: snap: Thanks! One thing I could try is change it to 770 on create mask and create mode.

Answer (score 1):

1. `chmod g+s` for parent directory
2. set `inherit permissions = yes`

and try again.

Comment: Sorry - no difference. I suspect that there is some configuration or quirk in FreeNAS that I've overlooked?